# How can we apply Non-maximum suppression to localize interest points?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

can anyone explain clearly the steps of Non-maximum suppression in a 3×3×3 neighborhood to localize interest points? 
I read many documents but I  mess up many things

Regards!

Comment: Which documents? What do you want to achieve (e.g. why do you use NMS?) Here is some documentation :https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/

Comment: Check this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122690/fast-peak-finding-and-centroiding-in-python/19137303#19137303